# Consume FFmpeg XCFramework from Objective-C, headers not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ffmpeg, linker-errors, xcframework

I built FFmpeg for Apple's platforms as an XCFramework. I used the script in https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script/pull/147 to do so.

I'm trying to now consume that framework inside a traditional iOS/macOS framework (named VideoEditing), that then is used inside my iOS app (soon to try and be Catalyst).

In `VideoEditing` I have linked to `FFmpeg.xcframework` and then in the app that uses `VideoEditing` I have linked & embedded `FFmpeg.xcframework`. Previously I was building FFmpeg as a standard static library, and using that from inside `VideoEditing` in a Objective-C++ wrapper so I can use it all from Swift.

In that Objective-C++ file I would import FFmpeg headers like `#import <libswscale/swscale.h>` To make that work, I had to set header search paths. How are you supposed to do it once you convert to the XCFramework? I've tried `@import FFmpeg`, `#import <FFmpeg/libswscale/swscale.h>`, `#import <FFmpeg/swscale.h>` as well as `#import <libswscale/swscale.h>`. In every case I just get a `file not found` error on the `import` line.

All of Apple's examples are showing it just in Swift with the framework vending a module. If I was to try and still set a header search path, you now have different headers per architecture.

[image: Overview of contents of XCFramework]

Comment: I am hitting the same issue, but with the 6.28.2 release of the Firebase/Crashlytics SDK. So this issue is not limited to FFmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

Try `@import FFmpeg` and also set `Enable Modules (C and Objective C)` to `YES` from build settings. Make sure that `Link Frameworks Automatically` is set to `YES`

Comment: I've already tried the `@import FFmpeg`, and I have the `Enable Modules (C and Objective C)` enabled. It doesn't work in this case because the FFmpeg framework is different from "normal" frameworks, so it doesn't build a module, so there is no module to import.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put header files parallel to xcframework and set header search path to that header file. xcframework is just like a single .a file, Xcode will not search headers inside xcframework.